# Perl regular expression that only keeps characters until first newline

Tags: regex, perl

When I try with a regular character instead of a newline such as `X`, the following works:

```
my $str = 'fooXbarXbaz';
$str =~ s/X.*//;
print $str;
```

→ `foo`

However, when the character to look for is `\n`, the code above fails:

```
my $str = "foo\nbar\nbaz";
$str =~ s/\n.*//;
print $str;
```

→ `foo
baz`

Why is this happening? It looks like `.` only matches `b`, `a`, and `r`, but not the second `\n` and the rest of the string.

Comment: Use `s` flag, `$str =~ s/\n.*//s;`

Comment: New line is special symbol and to much it you need to use special [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` metacharacter does not match a newline unless you add the `/s` switch. This way it matches everything after the newline even if there is another newline.

```
$str =~ s/\n.*//s;
```

Another way to do this is to match a character class that matches everything, such as digits and non-digits:

```
$str =~ s/\n[\d\D]*//;
```

Or, the character class of the newline and not a newline:

```
$str =~ s/\n[\n\N]*//;
```

I'd be tempted to do this with simpler string operations. Split into lines but only save the first one:

```
$str = ( split /\n/, $str, 2 )[0]
```

Or, a substring up to the first newline:

```
$str = substr $str, 0, index($str, "\n");
```

And, I'm not recommending this, but sometimes I'll open a file handle on a reference to a scalar so I can read its contents line by line:

```
open my $string_fh, '<', \ $str;
my $line = <$string_fh>;
close $string_fh;

say $line;
```